# More change() function jQuery doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

How this is not working? This only works for the first row of the table. Second row doesn't working. Thanks for all advice.
**

```
<table id="ticketTable">
  <tr><td>
          <select id="ticketSelect1">
             <option priceValue1="120" value="1" selected>Adult</option>
             <option priceValue1="110" value="2">Student</option>
          </select>
     </td>
     <td style="text-align:right"><span id="price1">120</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><th>Typ lístku</th><th style="text-align:right">Cena</th></tr>
        <tr><td><select id="ticketSelect2">
          <option priceValue2="120" value="1" selected>Adult</option>
          <option priceValue2="110" value="2">Student</option>
        </select></td><td style="text-align:right"><span id="price2">120</span></td></tr>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table tr td #ticketSelect1").change(function() {
        $('#price1').text($('option:selected').attr('priceValue1'));
    }).change();
  $("table tr td #ticketSelect2").change(function() {
        $('#price2').text($('option:selected').attr('priceValue2'));
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

**

Comment: Could you please edit question (click on "edit" link at the bottom of question) and clearly state what you are trying to achieve. As such,we don't even know what you are trying to do...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You surely want: `$('#price2').text($(this).find('option:selected').attr('priceValue2'));`  FYI, `priceValue2` isn't valid HTML attribute...

Comment: What Wolff is pointing out,     $('option:selected') is to general so it is grabbing both selected items, one from each select box.  The attr is only being applied against the first one so you will never get priceValue2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these selectors:

```
$('#price1').text($('#ticketSelect1 option:selected').attr('priceValue1'));
```

and

```
$('#price2').text($('#ticketSelect2 option:selected').attr('priceValue2'));
```